# How i can hide the border green on my player ? Phaser Js

Tags: phaser-framework

How i can hide the border green on my player ?

```
const config = {
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            debug: true,
            gravity: { y: 0 },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Juste change, `debug: false`

```
physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            debug: true,
            gravity: { y: 0 },
        }
    },
```